# How Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Item can be replaced in Constructor (DI)

Tags: magento2, inventory, di, object-manager

I want to use below code in Magento 2 constructor.

```
$stockItem = $objectManager->create('Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Item');
```

Can any one tell me the right way of calling above `create` class into constructor as a dependency class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
protected $stockItemFactory;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\ItemFactory $stockItemFactory,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->stockItemFactory = $stockItemFactory;
    ....
}
```

Then you can use in your class

```
$stockItem = $this->stockItemFactory->create();
```

Comment: Thanks +1 @ Marius. In same scenario, how get ($objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Item');) can be converted in to dependency calss.

Comment: The stock item instance is non injectable. I mean, it is, but you should not inject that directly. You may end up with problems if you do. Instead you should inject the stock item factory class and create the stock item instance when you need it.